# Ionic and Cordova ios deviceorientation

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, compass, device-orientation

from cordova-ios v6 this code doesn't work. He worked with version 5 and work in Android OS. Do you have any idea why?

```
function watchOrientation(callback) {
    if ("ondeviceorientationabsolute" in window) {
        console.log("ondeviceorientationabsolute");
        window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", callback);
    } else if ("ondeviceorientation" in window) {
        console.log("ondeviceorientation");
        window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", callback);
    } else {
        console.log("none device orientation event");
    }

    return callback;
}
```

I have just log "ondeviceorientation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, you must get the user permission first. Some idea:

```
function watchOrientation() {
  if (isIOS) {
    DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
      .then((response) => {
        if (response === "granted") {
          window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handler, true);
        } else {
          alert("has to be allowed!");
        }
      })
      .catch(() => alert("not supported"));
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", handler, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I had already tried but it shows the message 'not supported'. Maybe it requires some manipulation in Xcode?

Comment: Hello, because the call DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission() must be performed as a reaction to some user gesture. So e.g. you would show a dialog to user with a message and a button, explaining what's going to happen next. In button click handler, you hide the dialog and actually call that method.

Comment: An example of click handler is given here: https://dev.to/li/how-to-requestpermission-for-devicemotion-and-deviceorientation-events-in-ios-13-46g2 .

Comment: Ok it's look like great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using a plugin to target the native device orientation methods. Here are a few:

[Cordova Plugin](https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/device-orientation)

[Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/screen-orientation)

Comment: [cordova-plugin-device-orientation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation) appears to only be handling compass (heading) orientation. As far as I could see, there is today in 2023, absolutely no option to use the deviceorientation event, with Cordova (iOS > 12) in a "native" fashion -> without having to request permission, at every launch of the app, to use the orientation web API.